# Gathering data from a tree

Tags: python, search, tree

Consider i have the following list of trees:

### the data

```
data = [
    {'id': 'a',
     'x': 17,
     'children': [
         {'id': 'aa',
          'y': 14,
          'children':
              [{'id': 'aaa',
                'y': 14}]},
         {'id': 'ab',
          'y': 132}],
     },
    {'id': 'b',
     'x': 171,
     'children': [
         {'id': 'ba',
          'children': [
              {'id:': 'baa',
               'y': 4},
              {'id': 'bab',
               'y': 132}]}]
     }
]
```

### details

- Each node is represented by an id.
- No node knows its parent, just their children.
- Some of the nodes have a value for x, some of the nodes contain a value for y, some have neither.
- The depth of each tree can reach way deeper, like up to 10 levels.
- It is safe to assume that all ids are unique, but the node id does not reflect its position in the tree, i.e. parents or childrens ids. Each root node has a value for x and all leaf nodes have a value for y.

### task

I am now having node id and want to do the following with it.

1. If it has no value for x: ask their father(s) for x until I find a value for it.
2. If it has no value for y: ask their children for their values for y and sum it up.

### Examples:

- If the id of interest is `'aa'` I expect to obtain `x = 17` (coming from father node `'a'`) and `y=14`.
- If the id of interest is `'bb'` I expect to obtain `x = 171` (coming from father node `'b'`) and `y=136` (sum of childrens `y` values).

### so far

I came up with a recursive method which traverses the list of trees and successfully finds the correct id and stops the search afterwards. It also prints some debug including the level of recursion as space (easier for me to realize what is going on)

```
def tree_search(data, id, indent=''):
    stop_search = False
    for node in data:
        if stop_search:
            break
        print indent + node.get('id', '')
        if node.get('id') == id:
            print indent + "Found id"
            print indent + "gather x from father"  # but who is the father or the grandfather??
            print indent + "gather y from children"
            return True

        elif 'children' in node:
            print indent + "going deeper"
            stop_search = tree_search(node["children"], id, indent+' ')
```

But now I am stuck in how to get x from father or grandfather (whoever comes up with the first x) and how to find y from the children. As each node knows its children, the second seems easier.
Any hints on how to proceed on this?

Comment: Your preconditions state that nodes do not know their parents.  Given this, I don't see how you will ever perform task #1.

Comment: @JohnGordon The child node does not directly know its parent-node. But the father knows who their children are. When I use the method recursively, I could hand over the fathers id into the method. I am thinking of something like that, i.e. keeping a list of the route with me all the time.

Comment: maybe change the parameters of the method so that you are always passing in the latest value of x into the method ie tree_serach(data,id,x)` then before your recursive call do something like `x = node['x'] if 'x' in node else x`

Comment: since you are always traversing the tree just keep the last x encountered and the last y, then when you find the id you have them

Comment: as for the `y` part, just make a similar tree traversal function that passes in a current sum total and do a `sum += y if y in node` every time you hit a node